# Get a list of all fonts in VBA Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I am working in excel VBA and I want to get the list of all fonts in a combo box

Can any one help me please

I tried this code but i am getting error in listcount :

...

```
    Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)

    ' Put the fonts into column A

    *For i = 0 To FontList.ListCount - 1*
        combobox.AddItems  FontList.List(i + 1)
    Next i

    ' Delete temp CommandBar if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    TempBar.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to get the list of fonts (from Word)

```
Option Explicit

Sub listFonts()
    Dim wd As Object, fontID As Variant

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    For Each fontID In wd.FontNames
        Sheet1.cmbFonts.AddItem fontID
    Next
    wd.Quit
    Set wd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can get filename of font?

Comment: If you want to get the TTF filename for the 'cloud' fonts, there is a font list in a JSON format in C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\FontCache\4\Catalog json\ListAll.json. You should be able to parse the content in JSON format and get the names of those cloud fonts(TTf file names are converted to several numbers and put in separate folders.)

Answer (score 8):

The `FontList` should be returning a list that is indexed as 1 based. There is no need to start at 0.

```
Dim FontList
Dim i As Long
    
Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)

'Put the fonts into column A
For i = 1 To FontList.ListCount
    Debug.Print FontList.List(i)
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2) = FontList.List(i)
    'combobox.AddItems FontList.List(i)
    If i > 50 Then Exit For
Next i
```

That should build a list of fonts into column A of the [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). When that is working, remove the commenting so that it goes into your combobox.

Note that you will be getting a list of fonts that exactly duplicates the font list dropdown on the Home ribbon. There will likely be a few duplicates as that list duplicates a couple of fonts at the top of the list for the default Heading and Body categories.

Comment: thank you for response but it is not working throwing same error at listCount...  method listcount of object "-commandbacombobox" failed.

Comment: If you want to visualize the fonts, add this below the row starting with "Cells(Rows.Count":  `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Font.Name = FontList.List(i)`