# Excel vbscript return the number of fonts available in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to access the fonts available in excel?

I realise you can set the font by using:

```
 Range("A1:C1").Select
     With Selection.Font
         .Name = "Arial"
     End With
```

What I'd like to do is return the number of fonts in excel and then loop through them to get the name of each font.

Something like:

```
For Counter = 1 To excel.fonts
   ActiveCell = excel.font.Name
Next Counter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give the count and list the names:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim FontList
   Dim i As Long
   Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)

   MsgBox FontList.ListCount

   For i = 1 To FontList.ListCount
       Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2) = FontList.List(i)
   Next i
End Sub
```

*From a Jeeped Post*

[Jeeped Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080762/get-a-list-of-all-fonts-in-vba-excel-2010)

Comment: Love your work Gary, works like a charm. Have not come across Application.CommandBars before will look into it much appreciated.

Comment: @John  **Please note the code adapted from Jeeped's**

Comment: Thanks Gary appreciate you pointing me in the direction of Jeeped's post.