# Get list of fonts to which PowerPoint has access to and compare to user input

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint

I want to create a macro to set the font for all textboxes throughout PowerPoint.

I have the code to set them but for error handling I need to make sure that the font entered by the user is valid and therefore I need the full collection of fonts that PowerPoint has installed.

```
Private Sub ChangeTextFont_Click()

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim strFontName As String
Dim ValidFont As Font

strFontName = InputBox("Enter the name of the font to use for the text on the screens or press Cancel to keep the existing font.", "Enter Font Name")

If Trim(strFontName) = "" Then Exit Sub

'For Each ValidFont In <collection of all fonts powerpoint has>    <-------- this is my issue
    If strFontName = ValidFont Then
        With ActivePresentation
            For Each oSl In .Slides
                For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
                    With oSh
                        If .HasTextFrame Then
                            If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                                If oSl.Name <> "Config" Then
                                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = strFontName
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
            Next
        End With
    End If
'Next
End Sub
```

Ideally, I need the solution to only use PowerPoint (not launching Word as this has different font selection) and not be too long as this isn't supposed to be a difficult problem.

Comment: It may help if you understand that PowerPoint has no fonts installed; same is true of nearly all Windows/Mac programs. They rely on whatever fonts are installed on the system. You'd need to start by enumerating the system-installed fonts (via Windows API, I expect) and then eliminating bitmap fonts/PostScript fonts (neither of which PPT supports). Not sure how to go about the latter but a search on "winapi enumerate fonts" should get you started on the former.

Comment: I understand that powerpoint doesnt have fonts "installed" per say but wasnt sure how to phrase the question as it seemed to be using a different font list to word (more, not less) on my machine. After looking into this it was a caching issue and the fonts pulled from word were actually accurate so that solution is actually the way to go. Win API implementation is alot of effort in VBA imo so thats why i didnt want to go that route.

Comment: Glad you got that sorted out.  If you have a solution that works to pull a font list from Word, it'd be a service to the community to post it here.  Please consider doing that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end this was easiest to do pulling the list from word. I thought the list was different but that was due to caching fonts in the document I was comparing. Anyway for a good solution please check out the answer on this question: [Get a list of all fonts in VBA Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080762/get-a-list-of-all-fonts-in-vba-excel-2010)

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking in the `Microsoft Office\root\Office16\1033\PUBFTSCM\FONTSCHM.INI` file in your install directory and then parse through that...

Not sure what kind of data in there would be helpful, but it's a start.